# How to read the route table?

Tags: linux, ping, routing

Host: win8 ip: `192.168.1.102`

Virtual Machina: gentoo ip:`192.168.1.108`

I type the command `route -n` to see the route table.

The route table is :

```
root@gentoo-jl ~ # route -n    
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.253   0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.0       127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

and I don't know how to read the route table.

Can anybody tell me how to `read the table`?

And when I ping my host(192.168.1.102) in my vm machina(192.168.1.108), what is the path `from source to the destination`?

Comment: This question belongs at either superuser or serverfault.

Comment: With 'how to read the table' you mean how to understand what is expresses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man route` and  see the `OUTPUT` section.

Because the `192.168.1.102`  and `192.168.1.108` are in the same subnet. The ping packet will go to 192.168.1.102 directly.